# PHP refuses to display mysql data in framework grid

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, frameworks

I have been facing an issue of not being able to display data from MySQL database , when i do this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sandpit";
$password = "sand";
$dbname = "sandpit";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT title,url FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  echo $row["url"];
  echo "</br>";

} ?>
```

it works displaying this (http://puu.sh/eDkcF/a95af62676.png), 
but when i introduce a framework structure such as this to try to pretify it,

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
$username = "sandpit";
$password = "sand";
$dbname = "sandpit";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT title,url FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
 <doctype html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" >
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
 <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
   <body>
    <? while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
      echo'<div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
      <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
      <li>$row['url']</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>;
} ?>

</body>
</html>
```

according to what i am seeing, this does not work. It gives the result of this (http://puu.sh/eDjUD/0b5e9b1770.png).

The Framework i was using is Foundation, thanks for reading and offering help, the intended effect is to gain a block grid display.

Thank you

Charlie

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 It's the Foundation framework actually, not mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <? while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
  echo'<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
  <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
  <li>'.$row['url'].'</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>';
```

} ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is breaking because of quotes around `url`, and missing ' at the end.

```
<? while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
      echo"<div class='row'>
      <div class='large-12 columns'>
      <ul class='small-block-grid-3'>
      <li>$row['url']</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>";
} ?>
```

Comment: Oh, i actually used single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Because variables in single quotes are not parsed.

```
$name = 'John Wick';
echo 'Hi, $name'; // prints out 'Hi, $name'
echo "Hi, $name"; // prints out 'Hi, John Wick'
```

You should end quote before printing variable, or use double quotes (or here document synthax).

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
      echo'<div class="row">
               <div class="large-12 columns">
                   <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
                       <li>' . $row['url'] . '</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>';
} ?>
```

Comment: Ah, nice, Thank you for the examples, helped greatly